# Function in bash that generates random chars from /dev/random

Tags: bash, random

In my .bashrc file I appended the line `psswd() { LC_ALL=C tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9-!"@/#$%^&*()_+~' < /dev/urandom | head -c "$1";echo ;}` so that when I type `psswd n` in the terminal, it returns a string of n random characters. I would like to achieve the same but using /dev/random instead of /dev/urandom. However when I replace /urandom by /random, calling psswd does nothing (cannot even output a single random character after 1 hour), it's as if it's frozen. I don't know why it is so, and I know it's not a problem of not having enough entropy. The reason is that the command `od -An -N1 -i /dev/random` returns a random number.

Note that this last command returns a random number almost instantly if I type it say after a fresh reboot. But if I have invoked a call to psswd n with /random, then the command returns a random number after about 15 seconds. So the call to /random seems to have some effect on /dev/random even though it produces no output when I call the function psswd.

Overall I'd like to know how I could create a function that uses /dev/random to generate a random string of n characters.

Comment: May I ask why you want to use `/dev/random`? (See also http://sockpuppet.org/blog/2014/02/25/safely-generate-random-numbers/)

Comment: May I ask what the original problem was that you were asked to solve? And why `/dev/random` became so important to the solution of the original problem? You don't state what problem you set out to solve.

Comment: @melpomene : Basically for the fun of it. It's doing something I can do with urandom already, with random.

Ryan : I wasn't asked to solve any problem. All I want to do is to create a function in bash that generates a string of n random characters using /dev/random.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification: maybe useful? [10 Ways to Generate a Random Password from the Command Line](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/30184/10-ways-to-generate-a-random-password-from-the-command-line/)

Comment: That's basically where I got the idea to try such a thing, note that the penultimate command is very similar to the one I tried for my .bashrc file. But it uses /dev/urandom and not /dev/random.

Comment: I appreciate the PHP help but my goal is not to use the random characters. As I said, I'm only intersted in creating a function in bash that uses /dev/random to do its thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because `libc` will buffer `tr`'s output when it's not a terminal. On GNU/Linux, it's 4096 bytes. This means that `tr` has to produce 4096 bytes of output before `head` will see the first few bytes, even though it just asks for e.g. 8.

Since you only keep 78 out of 256 values, `/dev/random` has to produce on average `4096*256/78` = 13443 bytes of random output before you get your password.

`/dev/random` on my system, starting from an empty pool, took 26 seconds to generate 20 bytes. That means those bytes would take `13443*26/20` = 17475 seconds, or almost 5 hours, to generate a password.

At this point it would print the password, but it would require another bufferful for `tr` to realize `head` doesn't want anymore, so it would take another 5 hours before the command would exit.

If you disabled buffering, you would only need to generate `(8+1)*256/78` = 29 bytes, which would take a mere ~38 seconds. On GNU/Linux, you can do this with `stdbuf -o0`:

```
$ time { LC_ALL=C stdbuf -o0 tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9-!"@/#$%^&*()_+~' < /dev/random | head -c 8; echo; }
9D^MKbT)

real    0m36.172s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.010s
```

Answer (score 0):

> …when I replace `/urandom` by `/random`, calling psswd does nothing…

That happens.  [As Wikipedia explains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/random):

> In Unix-like operating systems, `/dev/random` is a special file that serves as a **blocking** pseudorandom number generator....
>
> A counterpart to `/dev/random` is `/dev/urandom` ("unlimited"/**non-blocking** random source [Emphasis added]

"Blocking" means that when it thinks it has run out of entropy, it stops producing numbers.  For example, on my system, the first command in your pipeline produces the following:

```
$ LC_ALL=C tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9-!"@/#$%^&*()_+~' < /dev/random  
~Sk(+!h
```

And, then, **it hangs**, presumably while waiting for more entropy.

This issue is discussed further [here](http://www.2uo.de/myths-about-urandom/) where it is argued that `/dev/urandom` is [good enough](http://www.2uo.de/myths-about-urandom/#experts).

#### Speeding it up

`tr` appears to buffer its output which delays the appearance of characters.  The work-around is to use `stdbuf` and, for me, this results in a substantial speed-up:

```
LC_ALL=C stdbuf -o0 tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9-!"@/#$%^&*()_+~' < /dev/random
```

Comment: Well it blocks without returning any output in my case. The command LC_ALL=C tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9-!"@/#$%^&*()_+~' < /dev/random does not output anything to me, even if I wait 1 hour. On the other hand using od returns something out of /dev/random. So it has enough entropy (as I said in my first post), to return at least a string of length 1. I don't know why using tr does not produce any output in my case.

Comment: `/dev/random` may have  to produce several characters before the output of `tr` has even one.  Further, `head is waiting for either `$1` characters or a SIGPIPE before it produces any output.  So, one character from `/dev/random` will only produce output if you asked for a 1-character password __and__ the character that `/dev/random` produced just happened to match the list in the `tr` command.

Comment: I see. Another question: why od gets an output though? od -An -N10 -t c /dev/random  returns numbers and special characters to me, almost instantly.